# ¿Como puedo cambiar el orden de una variable?

Tags: html, angular

Si tengo un formulario para elegir una fecha con un `input type="date"` y si el dato me lo muestra como
`date="2021-04-13"` pero yo ocupo que la variable este de la `forma= "13/04/2021"` para hacer un filtrado de datos  ¿Cómo puedo hacer este cambio?
Espero me puedan ayudar soy nueva en el desarrollo web.

Comment: Para que tengas mayores chances de reccibir ayuda te recomiendo leas [ask] y proveas un  [mcve]

Comment: intenta cambiar la configuracion del calendario de tu sistema, para que tenga efecto deberia ser windows(si usas windows) en castellano, setear a tu zona horaria y elegir el formato de fecha deseado. A veces ni asi funciona

Answer (score 0):

si estas trabajando con angular, puedes utilizar los datepipe, tal como se muestra en la documentacion oficial que te dejo por aqui, https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe.

Ahora mi consejo personal, yo utilizo las fechas con formato de string, por la facilidad que me da para manejar los datos, en tu caso, utilizaria como te comente, el datepipe que nos ofrece Angular, aqui un ejemplo.

```
let date: string = new Date() //en tu caso puedes recibir la fecha desde el input

// aqui utilizas el datePipe para convertir la fecha en el formato que necesites
date = this.datePipe.transform(date,'M/d/yyyy')

// Output: date= 13/04/2021
```